# Working with a string in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string, vb.net-2010

I know a string is just a set of characters. I have entered a string in to visual basic using a textbox.

```
message = textbox1.text
```

Can i now go and change the position of the characters in the string?

```
"Dogs" //string entered 
"odsg" //that must be output in textbox2
textbox2.text = Encrypted
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Try it. You can easily assign a new string to the `Text` property of the control.

Answer (score 4):

> Can i now go and change the position of the characters in the string?

No. Strings in .NET are immutable – they cannot be changed. In order to modify a string in VB, you call a function which creates a *new* string based off the modified contents of the old string. That’s what all the [string methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods.aspx) are doing.

It’s not entirely clear what your encryption function is supposed to do though. It seems to permute the letter positions, but what schema does it use for that?

Comment: Can you display a string in reverse?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, that’s actually easy because there’s a `Reverse` method. But beware, it doesn’t return a string, it returns `Char` collection. To use it, write `New String(message.Reverse())`.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph every second character moves one place back and the character that was in the position moves one forward

Comment: @Oded I can not try it if i dont know how to do it.

Comment: @Jon Here’s a hint: Iterate over the string in steps of 2, and at each iteration read the i+1-th character and then the i-th character, and append them to the result string. This is just one of many solutions but it requires the least concepts.

Comment: Can I handle a string as a array of characters and how?

Comment: @Jonathan - my point is that there is good documentation for both the language and the library. Reading this documentation and learning form it should be your first step.

Comment: Strings have a `ToCharArray` method which returns the array of characters.  Alternatively, if you need a truly mutable version of a string, you can use the `StringBuilder` class.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: You are right, .NET strings are immutable; however, the VB [Mid Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz5s6003.aspx) (not Function) looks like it would allow to do it. In reality it creates a new string in the background.

Comment: @Olivier Arrgh, don’t muddy the waters. Yes, you are technically right but it’s just confusing the issue further for beginners (“strings are immutable” is such a nice and easy rule), and using `Mid` is rigorously banned in good code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to create a kind of autocorrect function like the one MS Word uses. I would use a dictionary to store corrections. The wrong word would be used as key and the right word as value

```
Dim dict = new Dictionary(Of String, String)

dict.Add("dogs", "odsg")
dict.Add("fiel", "file")
...
```

After having setup the dictionary

```
Dim input As String = textbox2.Text
Dim corrected As String

If dict.TryGetValue(LCase(input), corrected) Then
    textbox2.Text = corrected
End If
```